# Corrupted memory segment when writing into it int by int

Tags: c

For having a standalone binary purpose I want to mount a payload in the RAM declaring its content int by int with something like this

```
int *payloadptr = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
payloadptr[0] = 0x11223344;
payloadptr[1] = 0x55667788;
```

This data setter script is generated automatically, I chose to do it int by int to take less space than char by char in my .c file
however when I dump the memory I can see that the bytes are totally mixed
But it is not the case with the char by char approach
What would possible cause this?

Comment: Note: Aside from endian issues, the `sizeof(int)` may not be 4 on some machines and may contribute to an unexpected memory dump.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't declare a static (maybe const) array with your data and create a copy with malloc+memcpy as needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The byte 'mix' as you say is caused by your CPU endianness. I assume you have an Intel-based CPU which architecture is Little Endian. I suggest you read about endianness here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness. A little endian architecture will cause int to be stored from the LSB to the MSB which will then invert the data. By using chars you do not create this endianness issue, hence the uncorrupted memory.

Answer (score 4):

If your intent is to store `int`'s in memory, then you *want* to write it `int` by `int`. The little endian nature of your machine will cause the `44` to appear at a lower memory address than `33`, but the machine will interpret the four bytes correctly as the original `int` that you wrote.

If your intent is to store individual bytes in memory, then you probably want to use the char-by-char approach since that will store the bytes in the order that you write it.